# Is it possible to use an array for element names in Xamarin?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have this code:

```
<local:CustomTextCell  x:Name="cfs0"  />
<local:CustomTextCell  x:Name="cfs1"  />     
<local:CustomTextCell  x:Name="cfs2"  />
```

Is there a way that I can use an array instead of using these three names?

The reason is that I would like to use a for loop to change the cell properties.

Comment: Add a name to their parent section, and loop through the child cells

Comment: Do this help? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/xaml-services/x-array-markup-extension#xaml-values

Comment: I take no credit for the solution, but I guess this is what you want... https://blog.pieeatingninjas.be/2017/04/20/trigger-propertychanged-of-indexed-property-in-xamarin-forms/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add a name to parent `TableSection` and use it loop through all the cells.

```
<TableSection Title="Parent" x:Name="parentSection">
    <local:CustomTextCell  x:Name="cfs0"  />
    <local:CustomTextCell  x:Name="cfs1"  />     
    <local:CustomTextCell  x:Name="cfs2"  />
</TableSection>
```

Add looping logic as following:

```
foreach (CustomTextCell textCell in parentSection)
{
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine($"{textCell.Text} - {textCell.IsChecked}");    
}
```